# Can't configure git, missing .gitconfig file

Tags: macos, git, bash

when I try to config Git I receive the following error:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Smith"
error: could not lock config file /Users/John/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

My root directory is completely missing a `.gitconfig` file. When I try to make a new one I receive this error:

```
$ touch ~/.gitconfig
touch: /Users/John/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

My git's location:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
```

I've tried reinstalling Git several times (running OSX Yosemite) and I'm still having the same issue. I also cannot locate any .gitconfig.lock files, as mentioned in some posts regarding this issue.

Comment: If `touch ~/.gitconfig` fails, your problem has nothing to do with git.  Is there any file there? Do other filenames work?

Comment: There is a file `.gitconfig@` at my root directory - what does the @ mean? I cannot view this file

Comment: The `@` suffix is something various programs add to indicate that this is a symbolic link.  Apparently it's a symlink to a non-existent file.  Find out where it was linked, and what happened to wherever-that-was, if you want to get the previous contents back.

Comment: Is there a way I can just have Git create the file from scratch again?

Comment: If you don't care what it might have been pointed at before then just delete the broken/dangling symlink and try the `git config` command again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I ended up solving this issue by reading the [Customizing Git](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) section of the documentation.

---

While I could not `touch` a new `.gitconfig` file in my root directory as stated above, I read that the first place Git looks for configuration values is in `etc/gitconfig` (note the lack of a `.` in the name).

So I created a file called `gitconfig` inside of the `etc` directory and filled it in with a sample `gitconfig` I found online, and added my `user` information to the top like so:

```
[user]
  name = John Smith
  email = jsmith@example.com
```

I was then able to commit as my usual self, however I still don't have a `.gitconfig` in my root, so I am unable to config Git using `git config --global`, and must do the configurations manually in `etc/gitconfig`.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I am running into the same problem and have yet to find a solution.

Comment: On windows, my gitconfig file was present at
C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig

Answer (score 1):

For me the .gitconfig file was missing.I tried reinstalling Git several times, however it din't help me. I resolved the issue by performing the below steps.

1. create a folder structure c:/dev/home if already not present.
2. Open the Windows command prompt. (Run as administrator)
3. From the Windows command prompt, run the command "git init"
4. Run the following command: 
   git config --global user.name "Example"
5. Run the following command: 
   git config --global user.email "Example@gmail.com"

The above steps will create the .gitconfig file in the path c:/dev/home and you will be able to set your desired username and email id.

On Windows systems, Git looks for the .gitconfig file in the $HOME directory (C:\Users\$USER for most people). So copy the file created in the above step to your Home directory by providing the required permission.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that. By adding .gitconfig file to the Home directory. Now it works fine.